# Error in wordpress / woocommerce user concurrency

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, concurrency, woocommerce

I have problems with a site hosted in GoDaddy with the following characteristics:

-Shared resources
  2 CPU colors
  2048 MB RAM
- 24/7 Support
- Metered storage
- 2048 MBps bandwidth

The site contains a Wordpress installation with Woocommerce, an approximate 200 products, the problem is that the host only supports up to 15 users at a time, according to a stress test, so there really is very few concurrent users, the site needs to host at least 60 users at the time, there are plugins installed, but not even deactivating the additional plugins the site is kept on the air with 15 people at the time.

Apparently there are so many queries to consult database that is why the decline of the site occurs.

My doubts are as follows, since I do not have much knowledge of wordpress:

Has anyone had something similar to me and how did he solve it?
Will another hosting plan be needed to make the site behave better?
What can I do to make the site support so many users, at least 60?

Thanks a lot for any answer.

Comment: Kindly, **this kind of question is off-topic on stackOverFlow…** This is a complicate matter and it depend of of hosting location. Personally I hate GoDaddy … For a Powerful cheap Woocommerce hosting with an excellent  7/7 24h/24h support (with skilled people), you should try SiteGround GrowBig or GoGeek hosting plans or their cloud hosting

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: $5-$10/m DigitalOcean VPS + nginx + PHP-FPM + MariaDB (with mysqltuner recommendations).

Shared servers are bad, you don't have 2 CPUs and 2GB RAM, don't fool yourself. OS software optimization will give you much more than playing with plugins on the bad server.

Of course it's possible that you have something bad in your code that drains all resources but in 97% cases it's server/OS question.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I appreciate it very much, at the moment the user is a little exceptional, do you know or have knowledge that harware could support at least 50 users at the time?

Comment: Everything depends on the code. There is no any special formula for "50 users online". However even cheapest VPS may cope with such online if you know how to cook OS and how to use cache. Hire a system administrator, wait for some hours and use it for months.